# xgboost in AWS EC2 throwing std::bad_alloc error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, xgboost

I am new to AWS and am struggling to run a model (xgboost) on a huge data with 8 million rows and 35 features. I am using m4.xlarge (ubuntu, 4 cpus and 16gb ram). I am getting the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not posting the code since it is a simple model.fit(train_data) command

The same model ran in my local system (i3 processor) though it took several hours. I am not able to get a straight forward answer from the internet. Is there a simple way to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: Your local system was able to expand into virtual memory, the AWS instance has no local storage, so it could not

Comment: Is there any work around for this? I mean, there should be some way to run models with huge datasets in Amazon EC2 instances. I heard even larger EC2 with 16cpus could throw an error like this

Comment: Use an instance with more memory, possibly one of the memory optimized ones. Or train on a subset of your data.